# Ubuntu Server 14.04 Hyper-V - No Internet

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to get Hyper-V to work with Ubuntu Server 14.04. I've made a new internal switch, and then shared my main adapter (not the virtual one) with the internal virtual switch. I still don't have Internet access on the virtual machine though.

Windows is saying the virtual switch has no Internet access, and it's unidentified. Not sure if that's the problem?

Comment: Not having Internet access sounds like your problem.

Comment: I do have Internet access, it just seems the virtual switch doesn't... i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Assuming that you mean that Hyper-V is the hypervisor and Ubuntu is the virtual machine, an internal virtual switch provides connectivity between virtual machines on the same virtual switch and those virtual machines and the host. It doesn't provide connectivity to the physical network.

Comment: OK, so give us some details to work with.

Comment: What details are you wanting?

Comment: @Mooticus - Did you read my comment?

Comment: Yes I did @joeqwerty I read somewhere that sharing the Internet with the internal virtual switch would work, but I guess they were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the description of each type of virtual switch in Hyper-V Manager you'll see what type of connectivity each type of virtual switch provides to the virtual machines.

An Internal virtual switch doesn't provide connectivity to the physical network.